# listbox parameter in method

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I pass a listbox datasource to asp.net class method?

Here is how the method is being called:

```
DataSet DS4DDL1 = mypj.searchPJ(Listbox data???,searchText);
```

Is is possible? Please modify the  above line to add the listbox datasource in this method.

Comment: It is impossible to answer your question given we don't know what mypj.searchPJ does.  Also the tone of your question is a little Do It for Me, which people won't like.

Answer (score 0):

You should access your listbox "data source" using the Items property which is of the type ListItemCollection. Your method would look like this:

```
DataSet DS4DDL1 = mypj.searchPJ(listBox.Items,searchText);
```

Comment: Is it possible to pass listbox values as dataset to this line, instead of session variable?  The name of list box is ProjList
ClientPJ mypj = new ClientPJ((DataSet)(Session"Client_ProjectDS"]));

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you have the values of the listbox on a session variable, then you don't need the listbox in the first place.

Comment: On page load yes it comes from a session variable, but the list item changes with dropdown selections - there are 5 dropdows and when 1st selection filters listbox, the 2nd DDL will search the listbox filtered by the 1st DDL.  Thats why I want to pass the listbox datasource to the search funtion.

Comment: I am getting null in in datasource, even though it not Null while passing it to teh method, what is wrong here?
DataSet DS4DDL1 = mypj.searchPJ((DataSet)(DDLProjectAssociation.DataSource), "chemistry");

Comment: Of course the DataSource is going to be null, since is not stored upon postback.

Comment: I am passing listbox.items to method but getting stucked on how to search listcollection in linq query, any help?
DataTable results = (from d in (projList.????
                             orderby d.Field<string>("Name") ascending
                             where d["Name"].ToString().Contains(ProjectName)
                             select d).CopyToDataTable();

Comment: var results = (from li in lb.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                            where li.Text == "Text"
                            select li);

Answer (score 0):

Method:
public DataSet searchPJ(ListBox ProjList???, String ProjectName)
    {
        DataSet DSToReturn = new DataSet();
        //logic to filter based on the column NAme

```
    DataTable results = (from d in ((DataSet)_MyDataset).Tables["Records"].AsEnumerable()
                         orderby d.Field<string>("Name") ascending
                         where d["Name"].ToString().Contains(ProjectName)
                         select d).CopyToDataTable();
            DSToReturn.Tables.Add(results);
    return DSToReturn;
}
```

Calling Method:
protected void ProjDDL1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String ProjectDDL1 = ProjDDL1.SelectedItem.Text;
        ClientPJ mypj = new ClientPJ((DataSet)(Session["Client_ProjectDS"]));
        //DataSet DS4DDL1 = mypj.searchPJ("chemistry");
        ListBox listBox = new ListBox();
        DataSet DS4DDL1 = mypj.searchPJ(listBox, "chemistry"); //Does not work
        ProjList.Items.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow dr in DS4DDL1.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            //only add item with valid UID
            if (dr[0].ToString().Trim().Length > 0)
                //use UID as the item value
                ProjList.Items.Add(new ListItem(string.Format("{0}", dr[0].ToString())));
        }

```
}
```